# Why does storage_path return 'app/..' directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using the grabzit library to convert video to gif using Laravels IoC container.

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\VideoToGif;
use App\Clients\GrabzIt\GrabzItClient;

class GrabzitService implements VideoToGif {

...


public function save(array $input)
{

    try {

        $id = $input["id"];

        $filename = $input["filename"];

        $result = $this->client->GetResult($id);

        $destinationPath = storage_path('media/gifs');

        file_put_contents($destinationPath . "/" . $filename, $result);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
ErrorException: file_put_contents(/app/storage/media/gifs/converted_file.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/app/Services/GrabzitService.php:65
```

Not sure if `storage_path()` is suppose to return the app directory when its actually in the project root.

What am I doing wrong here?

My project is on Heroku

Answer (score 0):

storage_path() returns the directory to /storage and isn't suppose to be the place where you put media contents. storage_path('media/gifs') returns /storage/media/gifs

Instead, you should store your media in public directory (public_path())

Comment: why is storage_path not returning the right path though: /app/storage <-- when in-fact it sits outside the app folder.

Comment: did you change your directory structure?

Comment: No, everything is stock.